# Stripe Elements Not Set In The Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, stripe-payments

I've to implement the `Stripe` form in an `ASP.NET` project and willing to do something like the below:

[Stripe Payment Form](http://jsfiddle.net/ywain/L96q8uj5)

This works fine and was able to create the form in the ASP.NET project with required files to integrate. But I am unable to write in the text boxes when imported all the required files from the JsFiddle. Though I have the following code with all references:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" />
<div class="group">
  <label>
    <span>Card number</span>
    <div id="card-number-element" class="field"></div>
    <span class="brand"><i class="pf pf-credit-card" id="brand-icon"></i></span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Expiry date</span>
    <div id="card-expiry-element" class="field"></div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>CVC</span>
    <div id="card-cvc-element" class="field"></div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Postal code</span>
    <input id="postal-code" name="postal_code" class="field" placeholder="90210" />
  </label>
</div>
<button type="submit">Pay $25</button>
<div class="outcome">
  <div class="error"></div>
  <div class="success">
    Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get exception in the console using the inspect feature of the browser - **Uncaught IntegrationError: The selector you specified (#card-number-element) applies to no DOM elements that are currently on the page. Make sure the element exists on the page before calling mount().** Anything that I missed here? One more thing, I am willing to get values from the element say card number. Is it actually possible to get that? Though I tried earlier but unable to retrieve values with name attribute of the input type generated by the elements as follows:

```
var cardNo = $('select[name=cardnumber]').val();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error likely means that your code is running before the DOM has fully loaded(on JSFiddle all code runs after the load event). You probably want to move the code that mounts the Stripe Element into a handler for the load event.

```
window.onload = function(){
  ...
  var cardNumberElement = elements.create('cardNumber', {
    style: style
  });
  cardNumberElement.mount('#card-number-element');
  ...
}
```

> I am willing to get values from the element say card number. Is it actually possible to get that?

No, for [PCI-compliance reasons](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance), Elements does not allow access to the raw card details.

Comment: OK but how could I use the form in production? Do I have to buy it? Currently I am using `Stripe` package in `ASP.NET` project. So I was hoping if I can customize accordingly  as the JsFiddle one - Thanks for the reply @karllekko.

Comment: Hmm, no, you don't have to buy anything here. I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you think you need the raw card details to process a payment? That's not true, Stripe creates a payment token that represents the details and you [call the API to charge](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#creating-charges) that token, you never need the raw details yourself.